# Number of solutions to system of polynomial equations $\!\bmod p^k$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, hensels-lemma

Consider the system of polynomial equations
$$
\begin{cases}
a(X^2+Y^2)^2-2b(X^2+Y^2)+4(bX-cY)X \equiv 0 &\pmod{p^k} \\
d(X^2+Y^2)^2+2c(X^2+Y^2)+4(bX-cY)Y \equiv 0 &\pmod{p^k}
\end{cases}
$$
in two variables $X,Y$, with $k\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}$ and parameters $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$. How does one count or obtain an upper bound for the number of solutions $X,Y\in(\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\mathbb{Z})^\times$?

So far I have thought of the following. Fixing a value for $X$, if the parameters $a,b,c,d$ are "nice enough", there can be at most 4 solutions for a value of $Y$ per equation due to Hensel's lemma. But it is not clear to me how one controls the number of admissible values for $X$. Is there a specific technique that one can use to get an idea of how the number of solutions behaves, perhaps in terms of the $p$-adic valuations of the parameters $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Eliminating $Y$ between the two equations [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=resultant%28a+%28X%5E2%2BY%5E2%29%5E2-2b+%28X%5E2%2BY%5E2%29%2B4%28b+X-c+Y%29X%2C+d+%28X%5E2%2BY%5E2%29%5E2%2B2c+%28X%5E2%2BY%5E2%29%2B4%28b+X-c+Y%29Y%2C+Y%29) an octic in $X$ which factors into $X^4$ times a biquadratic in $X$, so it has at most $5$ distinct roots in general.
$$
256 X^4\,(b^2 + c^2)^2\,\big((a^2 + d^2)^2 \,X^4 + 2 (a b + c d) (a^2 + d^2) \, X^2 - (a c - b d)^2\big) = 0
$$
The "nice" resultant suggests the question is a step in a larger problem, so more context could help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Unfortunately, the context is not very helpful to my already quite vague question, as I was mostly looking for a way to bound solutions to such systems of equations in general; the resultant is a very nice tool that I hadn't thought of. :)

Comment: *to bound the number of solutions